Generating GCP Cloud storage pre signed URL from Cloud Run
Im having a Python code in cloud run, which will create a pre signed url for Cloud storage object. But Im getting an error message back

you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.

Below are the roles and permissions granted to the service account

Here is the Python code
def generate_upload_url(self, payload):
        """Generate the upload URL for file"""
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(payload["bucket"])
        blob = bucket.blob(payload["file"])

        download_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            expiration=3000,
            method="PUT",
            version="v4",
            content_type="application/octet-stream"
        )
        return download_url

In one of the site I noticed a command, which seems to resolve the issue at least in my local machine
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=[SERVICE-ACCOUNT]

But I dont like the approach of getting the json credential file inside Cloud run functions. Please let me know how to make it work.
